# Get max/min of an attribute sorted based on another key

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, lodash

Suppose I have an array of json objects like:

```
[{ customerId:1, orderId:1-1, orderAmount:100
   customerId:2, orderId:2-1, orderAmount: 125
   customerId:1, orderId: 1-2, orderAmount: 112
  ............
}]
```

And I want to find the highest (or lowest) order per customer like

```
[{customerId:1, orderId:1-2, orderAmount:112},{.....}]
```

Is it possible to do either using any language construct (I am using Node.js) or lodash. I think can either sort by customerId or sort by orderAmount is straightforward in lodash but not the above combination

The only other way I can think of is double forEachOf (async) loop which may not be very efficient

Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy) with with `order` ascending or descending to decide if lowest or highest. Group by `custormerId`, and take the 1st item from each customer orders:

```js
function getMinMax(orders, min) { // orders - array of orders, min - true if minimum, undefined / false if maximum
  var order = !!min ? 'asc' : 'desc'; 
  
  return _(orders)
  .orderBy('orderAmount', order) // orderBy the orderAmount property, with order determining highest or lowest
  .groupBy('customerId') // group all orders by customer id
  .map(function(orders) { // create a new array of just the 1st order of each customer, which will be the highest or the lowest
    return orders[0];
  }).value();
}

var orders = [{
  customerId: 1,
  orderId: '1-1',
  orderAmount: 100
}, {
  customerId: 2,
  orderId: '1-2',
  orderAmount: 128
}, {
  customerId: 2,
  orderId: '1-3',
  orderAmount: 12
}, {
  customerId: 1,
  orderId: '1-3',
  orderAmount: 113
}, {
  customerId: 2,
  orderId: '1-1',
  orderAmount: 125
}, {
  customerId: 2,
  orderId: '4-1',
  orderAmount: 11
}, {
  customerId: 1,
  orderId: '1-2',
  orderAmount: 25
}];

var highestOrders = getMinMax(orders); 

console.log('highestOrders', highestOrders);

var lowesetOrders = getMinMax(orders, true); 

console.log('lowesetOrders', lowesetOrders);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're welcome :) As a new user to stackover, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) short guide.

Answer (score 0):

[`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) allows you to specify an array of fields to sort with. You can use:

```
var output = _.sortBy(input, ['customerId', 'orderAmount']);
```

---

If you want to also group the objects into arrays so that it is easier to find the max & min for each `customerId`, you can use [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) and then sort.

```
var output = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(input, 'customerId'), function(val) {
  return _.sortBy(val, 'orderAmount');
});
```

This would produce a structure like:

```
{
  "1": [
    { customerId: 1, orderId: "1-2", orderAmount: 112 },
    { customerId: 1, orderId: "1-1", orderAmount: 100 }
  ],
  "2": [
    { customerId: 2, orderId: "2-1", orderAmount: 125 }
  ]
}
```